# Write newlines before HTTP header

Tags: http, http-headers

Recently I was trying to upload large files (hundreds of megabytes) through a browser over HTTP. It may take a long time for the request to complete, so the browser (Chrome 43) seemed to be disconnecting after about 5 minutes of not receiving a response from my server. I learned and confirmed that if I just streamed newlines in my HTTP response, the browser wouldn't disconnect, and my upload succeeded after about 10 minutes.

I want to use this trick to prevent disconnects, but I think this means I have to set my HTTP response and headers before streaming the newlines. I'd like to still be able to set 201, 202, 400, 500 etc status codes if something goes wrong in the request.

I was thinking I might prepend the HTTP header with newlines, and then send the headers, and then the response. Is that allowed / do all browsers support that? If not, is there a better way to prevent disconnects?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear to be disallowed by [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html):

> 6.1 Status-Line
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting of the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its associated textual phrase, with each element separated by SP characters. No CR or LF is allowed except in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>   Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
> ```

Though I'm still curious if browsers ignore this and trim leading whitespace anyway.